# Can a graviton be a spin-2 particle made from 2 spin-1 particles?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, bosons

Presumably there would be a force holding the 2 spin-1 particles together.

Comment: What does this have to do with QFT? That the bound state of two spin-1 particles may have spin-2 is a completely general phenomenon, why would you need a specific QFT for that?

Comment: I mean for example a graviton

Comment: The graviton is not supposed to be a composite particle.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinberg%E2%80%93Witten_theorem

Answer (score 4):

A commenter links to the [Weinberg-Witten theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinberg%E2%80%93Witten_theorem):

> In theoretical physics, the Weinberg–Witten (WW) theorem, proved by Steven Weinberg and Edward Witten, states that massless particles (either composite or elementary) with spin j > 1/2 cannot carry a Lorentz-covariant current, while massless particles with spin j > 1 cannot carry a Lorentz-covariant stress-energy. The theorem is usually interpreted to mean that the graviton (j = 2) cannot be a composite particle in a relativistic quantum field theory.

Comment: This theorem is background dependent since we are considering perturbation on Minkowski space time. Wikipedia states that it is not applicable in GR. So is this theorem only approximately true?

Comment: @KP99 GR is still *locally* Lorentz invariant (GR reduces to special relativity over short enough intervals of time and space). Short distances = high energies in quantum mechanics because of the uncertainty principle. So generally one would still expect the Weinberg-Witten theorem to be relevant even on curved background geometries. Furthermore, you can still think about graviton scattering in Minkowski space, meaning graviton scattering in the absence of a background gravitational field, in which case the WW theorem would apply exactly.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you. This explanation intuitively makes sense